# Trivializations of Möbius band

Tags: fiber-bundles, mobius-band

If $E=\mathbb{R}\times (-1,1)$ and $\forall (x,t), (y,t^{'}) \in \mathbb{R}\times (-1,1)$, 
$$(x,t)\backsimeq(y,t^{'})\Leftrightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{Z} ; x=y+2n\pi , t=(-1)^{n} t^{'} $$
$$x\backsim y \Leftrightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{Z} ; x=y+2n\pi$$
$S^{1}= \mathbb{R}/ \backsim$ and $E= \mathbb{R}\times (-1,1)/\backsimeq$

$E$ is called Möbius band.
Now, I would like to investigate its trivializations and structure group.
Suppose  $\pi: E\to S^{1}$ that $[x,t]\mapsto [x]$ and $U_{1}=(0,2\pi)/\backsim, U_{2}=(-\pi,\pi)/\backsim$ and $(\pi, \phi_{i}):\pi^{-1}(U_{i})\to U_{i}\times \mathbb{R}$ that for all $i\in\{1,2\}$, $[x,t]\mapsto([x],t)$.
 Translation map is in the following form $$(\pi, \phi_{2})\circ (\pi, \phi_{1})^{-1}:(U_{1}\cap U_{2})\times \mathbb{R}\to (U_{1}\cap U_{2})\times \mathbb{R}$$,

$$([x],t)\mapsto [x,t]=[x,t]\quad if\quad   x\in (0,\pi)\quad  and \quad  [x,t]=[x-2\pi,-t]\quad  if \quad  x\in (\pi, 2\pi)$$
Now,  using $(\pi, \phi_{2})$, we have:
$$([x],t)\mapsto t \quad if\quad   x\in (0,\pi)\quad  and \quad ([x],t)\mapsto  -t\quad  if \quad  x\in (\pi, 2\pi)$$
Is it correct?

Why does it have structure group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{2 }$?

Help me , please.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: What? I do not underestand your meaning?